# Why calling a user defined function needs the owner name when calling a stored procedure doesn't?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Why calling a user defined function need the owner name when calling a stored procedure doesn't ?
Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the schema name?  Owner is the user that created it.

It distinguishes the function from a built-in function.  "System" stored procedures and functions live in the master database (so it can be searched), while built-in functions (things like `DATEADD`) reside in the database engine themselves.

I guess it's more difficult when you specify `SELECT MyFunction()` for the database engine to work out whether you mean a function that lives in a database, or a built-in function.

Comment: Thanks Andy!
Yes I mean the schema name.
Well, what you said helps but I do not totally agree with you. Why don't we need to distinguish user's stored procedure vs built-in stored procedure?

Comment: Because stored procedures only ever live in the database, they're never built-in, so the engine can search both the master database and the current database. That's why you should try not to name your procedure sp_something.  If SQL sees sp_ at the start of your procedure it searches the master database first.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I understand it now.
As Ian said below, we only need the schema for scalar functions. For table-value functions, we don't need ones. I would like to hear your thinking about this Andy. Please discuss with me.

Comment: Yeah that's probably right, because as far as I'm aware there are no built-in functions that return a table - they all operate on, and return, scalar values.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually only the case for scalar-valued functions.

Comment: Yeah, you're right Ian. I've just tested and confirm what you said! So from this, can we say that "there's no system table-value function" ?

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with Andy above, I answer my own question here:
Stored procedures are stored in the current database of the connection when created. In the mean time, functions are stored two locations: in the database engine (the scalar-value built-in ones) and in the current database of the connection (the user-defined ones).
So the when calling the user-defined scalar-value functions, we need the schema name prefix to distinguish them vs the built-in ones. We don't need this prefix for the other types of functions and for the stored procedures.